# How can I include VTK module in my Docker image or container?

Tags: docker, vtk

I'm using an image downloaded from docker hub. I want to use code from `https://github.com/maudzung/Complex-YOLOv4-Pytorch`

In my environment, to activate the code, it is necessary to install VTK and PyQT5 (for installing mayavi in link) in my container.

Here, In my knowledge, I need to modify my image file and rerun it!

Can you give me advice on how to modify my image file to include above requirements?

I tried to "pip" module but there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand the question. The `Complex-YOLOv4-Pytorch` do not require `VTK`, `PyQt5`:

https://github.com/maudzung/Complex-YOLOv4-Pytorch/blob/2f32996fc4d8942a156545596f76bbc267d5cd8e/requirements.txt#L1-L8